# Order of the factor group by the center equals order of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

My question is:

What are the implications if the order of the factor group $G/Z(G)$ is equal to the order of the group $G$?

I know that $|G/Z(G)|=|G|$ if $|Z(G)|=1$ meaning the center is trivial.

Since $G/Z(G)$ is the set of all left cosets then if for example say $G=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ then 
$G/Z(G)=\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{e\}\}$

What can I say about $G$ based from these? Can I say that $G$=$Z(G)$?

This question arose when I tried to answer the following question:

[Every group of order 203 with a normal subgroup of order 7 is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286662/every-group-of-order-203-with-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-7-is-abelian/484655#484655)

Here is my solution to this question:

Here is a try at a solution but I'm having trouble showing something.

Consider the center of G $Z(G)$. We know that $Z(G)\leq G$

By Lagrange's theorem $|Z(G)|$ must divide $|G|$.

So therefore the possible order of  $Z(G)$ are $1, 7, 29, 203$.

If $|Z(G)|=203$ then $Z(G)=G$ and $H\leq G=Z(G)$ and $G$ is abelian.

Now $|Z(G)|\neq29$ because if $|Z(G)|=29$ then the order of the factor group $G/Z(G)$ is $|G|/|Z(G)|$ which is equal to $203/29 = 7$.

So  order of $G/Z(G)$ is prime $\implies$ $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\implies$  $G$ is abelian $\implies G=Z(G)$ which is a contradiction since $|G|=203$.

The same argument also shows that $|Z(G)|\neq7$.

I wanted to show that $|Z(G)|\neq1$.

So I'm asking what are the implications of having a trivial center.

Thank you.

Comment: You already know that $Z(G)$ is trivial, so clearly $G=Z(G)$ only when $G$ is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

"then $G/Z(G)=\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{e\}\}$" -- but it is possible $\{a\}=\{b\}=\ldots$.

Comment: From this '$|Z(G)|=|G|$'. I assumed that no $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are equal otherwise '$|Z(G)|\neq|G|$'

Comment: A left coset $\{a\}$ has the same order as $Z(G)$. If  $|\{a\}|>1$ and  $x\in\{a\}$ then  $\{x\}=\{a\}$.